# How to get a guaranteed invalid iterator (for vector)?

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a container class which is essentially (showing relevant parts only)

```
class Foo {
    typedef std::map<int, std::vector<int>> data_t;
    data_t data;
    struct iterator {
        data_t::iterator major_it;
        data_t::mapped_type::iterator minor_it;
        // ...
    };
    iterator begin();
    iterator end() {
        return { data.end(), /* XXX */ };
    }
};
```

As you see, I want to have iterator implemented for this container. The iterator shall go through each node in map and iterator through each element in the vector the node refers to. I have no problem implementing the iterator, but I had some trouble implementing `end()` for the container.

The iterator consists of two levels of iterators, and for the past-end iterator, `major_it` will have to be `data_t.end()`, but I won't have anything to initialize `minor_it`.

In the same vein, `begin()` will also be broken when the map is empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector::iterator` is always invalid when value-initialized:

```
std::vector<…>::iterator invalid_iter_value = {};
```

Incidentally, it's *unusable* when default-initialized (i.e. uninitialized), which might be good enough for you. If `major_it` is already at the end, then simply don't access `minor_it`.

```
std::vector<…>::iterator unusable_iter_value;
```

However, note that it's also illegal to copy the default-initialized object, so value-initialization is a good idea unless you're customizing the copy constructor and operator.

Comment: Maybe I'm just paranoid. Is a branch necessary in `begin()` to filter out the case when map is empty?

Comment: @YiFei Make it UB :P

Comment: @Rakete1111, don't know if good for future visitors, but I upvoted :P.

Comment: To add: It is well defined to compare a value initialized iterator to another value initialized iterator, while a default initialized iterator cannot be compared to anything.